# Magento Jquery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery, magento

Good day,

I'm trying to add a jquery UI datepicker to my Magento store.  Everything works as it should outside MAgento, but when I add it to Magento nothing happens.  Ive added the jquery file to the appropriate folder in magento js, and correctly added the file to the page.xml file. I've been playing around with the noconflict.js but so far no joy.  My code is below.  Please let me know if I am doing something incorrect or if there may be a step I skipped.

Thank you

```
$j(function() {
$j( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your version of Magento.
For later version, you should already have a jQuery bundled in Magento and a noConflict done for you (since magento is historically still using prototypeJs).

So if you are on one of the latest version, then you should just be ok with `$j` for jQuery, so this way.

```
$j(function() {
    $j( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

Because Magento is doing

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

for you in the file `/js/lib/jquery/noconflict.js` already

If not, then you will have to have the line `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();` either in a file included just after your jQuery lib, or at the very last line of your jQuery lib.

One other possibility is to simply do

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the info.  I ended up figuring it out.  Perhaps adding jquery UI to the XML was needed.  DERP